# The the post id from image id

Tags: images

Lets say I have the ID of an image. Is there a way that I get all the posts that have that image as their featured image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The featured image is stored as post meta with the key `_thumbnail_id`, so you could use a [meta query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) to get posts with a specific thumbnail:

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array( 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => '_thumbnail_id',
            'value' => $attachment_id,
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Where `$attachment_id` is the ID of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same but for content images, it seems that there is no other way than parsing the content with regex.
Featured image is easy, ¿ do you know how to do the same with content attachments?